# Managed class parameter in unmanaged function?

Tags: c++, c++-cli

I'm attempting to re-write my C# library, somewhat merged with my C++ implementation, in managed C++.

I have a managed base class that I need to use within unmanaged classes as well.

I have an unmanaged class (enclosed in #pragma unmanaged) that has a function that takes my base class as a parameter. It then adds it to a vector to be referenced later.

For some reason it isn't recognizing `gcroot` as a keyword. I assume because its in #pragma unmanaged code.

How can I accomplish this?

Thanks,

Alex

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're correct. Anything in #pragma unmanaged has to be "regular" C++ (it can't include C++/clr code).  If you want a native class to use gcroot, just don't put the code in #pragma unmanaged (since it *does* contain managed code).

Why do you need it to be in #pragma unmanaged?

Comment: I need an entire class to be unmanaged. Sorry if I'm doing something wrong lol, I'm still trying to figure it all out.

Comment: Okay, nevermind, just realized that any class/struct that isn't declared with ref or value is automatically unmanaged, lol. But Visual Studio still isn't recognizing gcroot as a keyword.

Comment: gcroot is not a keyword.  You need to #include <vcclr.h>